# Возможно ли создать xpath запрос который выдаст результат исключающий элементы с неким конкретным чайлдом

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

Например
есть набор дивов

```
<div>
  <div class="item"><b><i>1234</i></b> </div>
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item"><b>3</b> </div>
  <div class="item"><i>4</i> </div>
  <div class="item"><b><i>asdf</i></b> </div>
</div>
```

возможно ли написть **xpath** так, что бы нашло все элементы класа **item** которые в себе **НЕ имеют** `<b><i>` чайлда

фактически, что бы нашло только

```
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item"><b>3</b> </div>
  <div class="item"><i>4</i> </div>
```

Но не нашло

```
  <div class="item"><b><i>1234</i></b> </div>
```

и

```
  <div class="item"><b><i>asdf</i></b> </div>
```

Или же сразу что б была возможность проверить в браузере, мне нужно захватить все `//li[contains(@id,'result')]` окроме тех, у которых имеется чайлд `//li[contains(@id,'result')]/div/div/div/div/h5`

на странице поиска амазона:
https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=treking+poles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может быть вот это подойдет:

```
div/div[not(b/i)]
```

Comment: неа, не сработает. Я немного подкоректировал вопрос, сразу в конце добавил.

Comment: @Andrew,Я подправил

Comment: Сработало! //li[contains(@id,'result')][not(./div/div/div/div/h5)] запахало! Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Или такой вариант

```
//div[@class='item' and not(b/i)]
```